# Invalid Operation Exception was unhandled for vb

Tags: vb.net

Not sure if this is the right forum but...

I have been working on a project for a while now and have been able to build both debug and release compiles. Suddenly, I cannot build any thing! I get the following error:

An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.AcroPDFLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have done several searches on the web and found no solution. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: To improve your question, please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

And your question is??

Perhaps try following the exception prompt and adding the missing assembly reference in your project?

But still, welcome to SO and please have a read on SO guidelines before posting any questions. Asking a good question will help others better understand about your issues, and in return have them resolved faster.

https://stackoverflow.com/tour

https://stackoverflow.com/help